# Invoking parent function with instance from child in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have two components, Parent component creates the a dom using child component. Finally more and two child component is created.

While creating a child component a **Click Event** that is declared in parent is passed as props. I expect the child to evoke the function with its instance.

But the problem I face is when the click event evokes from the child; The instance will be from the last child.

Please have a look on the code and let me know where am I going wrong

```
    var AccordionControl = React.createClass({

    handleClick: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.refs["accordionHeaderComponent"].toggleHeaderDisplay(true);
    },


    createMenuElement: function (menuContentProps, index) {
        var boundClick = this.handleClick.bind(this, index);

        var headerContent = <MenuHeader key = {index}
        clickEvent = {boundClick}
        ref = "HeaderComponent"
        menuHeaderProps = {menuItemProps}
        />;
     },

    render: function(){
                for(var index=0; index<menuData.length; index++) {
                       wrapperContent.push(this.createMenuElement(menuData[index],index));
                }
                return wrapperContent;
    }})

    var MenuHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      var menuHeaderProps = this.props.menuHeaderProps;
      return  <div onClick={this.props.clickEvent} > </div >
    }
})
```

Comment: You've to  use a IIFE to form a closure to assign the index value to click handler. Else it will always take the last value of the for loop

Comment: Maybe in your function "createMenuElement" you forgot call " return headerContent"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :) The Problem here is I am using the "refs" as a string inside a loop and this is getting over written by the following component in the loop.

So the Last element that replaced will be on the call. If the "Refs" is replaced with dynamic string like
 `ref={"HeaderComponent"+index}` 
then you will have collection of components to choose :)

Then this will be 
`var componentKey = "accordionHeaderComponent1";
this.refs[componentKey ].toggleHeaderDisplay(true);`